# What component does Stack Overflow use to generate graphs/charts?

Tags: discussion, reputation-graph, design, graphs

What component does Stack Overflow use to generate graphs/charts, like the one used to show reputation history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: This is no longer accurate, although I don't know what the new answer is.