# What graphing library do you use?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which component Stack Overflow uses to generate graphs/charts ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35671/which-component-stack-overflow-uses-to-generate-graphs-charts)

When I go to the reputation tab of my profile, I see a nice graph of my reputation. I was reading in a post somewhere that the StackOverflow engine uses jQuery. What do you use for the chart?

I'm guessing [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)?

If so, what plugin do you use for the drag selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), and as far as I know, the drag selection is an in-built feature of the library.

You may want to check out this example:

http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/selection.html

```
var options = {
    series: {
        lines: { show: true },
        points: { show: true }
    },
    legend: { noColumns: 2 },
    xaxis: { tickDecimals: 0 },
    yaxis: { min: 0 },
    selection: { mode: "x" }   // This is the key to enable selection
};

// ..

var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, options);
```